# SQLiteDatabase insert returns -1

Tags: android, sqlite

Help please. I am stuck. Will someone tell me why i have AssertionFailedError on JUnit testing. I have no idea why the SQLiteDatabase db insert method returns -1.

the error directs to the line 50: assertTrue(locationRowId != -1);

```
public void testInsertReadDb() {
    // Test data we're going to insert into the DB to see if it works.
    String testLocationSetting = "99705";
    String testCityName = "North Pole";
    double testLatitude = 64.7488;
    double testLongitude = -147.353;

    // If there's an error in those massive SQL table creation Strings,
    // errors will be thrown here when you try to get a writable database.
    WeatherDbHelper dbHelper = new WeatherDbHelper(mContext);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING, testLocationSetting);
    values.put(LocationEntry.COLUMN_CITY_NAME, testCityName);
    values.put(LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LAT, testLatitude);
    values.put(LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LONG, testLongitude);

    //long locationRowId;
    long locationRowId = db.insert(LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    // Verify we got a row back.
    assertTrue(locationRowId != -1);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "New row id: " + locationRowId);
```

Here is the error:

```
Running tests
Test running started
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at com.example.krisemmanuel.sunshine.test.TestDb.testInsertReadDb(TestDb.java:50)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1729)

Finish
```

Here is a screen of the error:
http://picpaste.com/debughelpplease-IuEAYaNu.png

And the Android Studio project folder:
http://krisg.net/java/Sunshine.rar

I don't know why insert() method of SQLiteDatabase db returns -1. I am trying to test if the insert to SQLite works, but it fails on the testing.

Comment: you question is not clear. you should describe detail. if your question not clear, you can't get any suggestion.

Comment: hello B M, i have revised my question to make it clearer. Sorry. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `SQLiteDatabase.insert()` fails, it just logs the error message and returns -1.

To get the exception, use [insertOrThrow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) instead.

Comment: You Sir just oiled a cog :) Thank you very much. I found the bug finally! Just lacking a space in the SQL table creation. Thank you so much again